# preview next slide in openoffice presentation?

Tags: openoffice-impress

is there away to show the next slide coming up and the current one on the laptop but only have the current one displaying on the projector?

Comment: This should probably go on SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Office has a feature called "presenter mode" which allows the laptop to display the current slide, notes, a timer, and a preview of the next slide.

There is an extension that appears similar to this that is currently in development but has a beta available that you can see [here.](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Presenter_Screen) Note, you need at least OpenOffice.org 3.0 beta for this extension.